# What is Richard’s paradox?

Tags: reference-request, richards-antimony

I am about to try to read through the Wikipedia [article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard%27s_paradox) and invite anyone to give an introduction or clarification.

(I first learned of this paradox from Gödel’s paper on “formally undecidable propositions of Principia Mathematica”, where it’s called Richard’s antimony).

Comment: What specifically are the obscure points?

Comment: [Richard's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard%27s_paradox) shows an example of *diagonalization* (see Cantor's Theorem as well as Godel's Theorem): "The paradox begins with the observation that certain expressions of natural language define real numbers unambiguously, while other expressions of natural language do not. We assume that we can write an infinite list of English phrases that define real numbers unambiguously, arranged in lexicographival oder.  Now define a new real number r as follows [.... *diagonalization*]. 1/2

Comment: The newly obtained expression defines a real number **r** that must be one of the numbers of the list. However, **r** was constructed so that it cannot equal any of the numbers in the list; thus, **r** is an undefinable number). This is the paradoxical conclusion." 2/2

Answer (score 1):

See [van Heijenoort's *Sourcebook*, page 142](https://www.google.it/books/edition/From_Frege_to_G%C3%B6del/tWn9DwAAQBAJ) for the English translation of original (1905) [Jules Richard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_Richard_(mathematician))'s letter.

The context is the discussion about [early set theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-early/#CritPeri) with the origin of the so-called paradoxes.

[Richard's one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard%27s_paradox#Description) is also historically relevant because, like well-known [Russell's one (1903)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/#HOTP), does not use the "more technical" concepts of cardinal number, ordinal, well-order with which the previous paradoxes (Cantor, Burali-Forti, König) has been formulated, but uses only the most basic concepts of set theory: element, subset, property.

Giuseppe Peano in 1906 gave a penetrating comment regarding the paradox: "Richard's example does not belong to mathematics, but to linguistics; an element that is fundamental in the definition of [the diagonal number] **N** [the numebr formed having **0** as integral part and in its *n*th decimal place...] cannot be defined in an exact way (according to the rules of mathematics)."

This comment foreshadows the key-point of subsequent distinction between *language* and *meta-language*.

The relation with [Gödel's proof](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#DiaSelRef) is explicitly noted by Gödel himself (page 598 of the English translation in the same *Sourcebook*): the proof uses diagonalization to attain a sort of self-reference, because the formal language of arithmetic is used to "speak of itself" through encoding of expressions and representability of recursive relations.

---

A brief discussion of the paradox is contained into [Yanofsky's paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3109884) that you already know.

In a nutshell, we may conclude that Richard's paradox (like Russell's one and similar) are due to the fact that if we want to achieve rigour (e.g. in mathematics) we have to limit the possibility of natural language of "speaking of everything", the [language itself](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/self-reference/) included  (see Peano's remark above).